# como divido una columna con datos int y varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

si tengo una columna como la siguiente

```
Column_value |
perro        |
2            |
gato         |
1            |
pez          |
8            |
```

Con que funcion logro que me de resultado algo asi:

```
Column_valueInt | Column_Value_varchar
2               | NULL
1               | NULL
8               | NULL
NULL            | perro
NULL            | Gato
NULL            | Pez
```

Comment: Ya intentaste usando CASE?

Comment: si pero no se que logica usar

Comment: Que tipo de valor es la columna de la tabla?

Comment: es varchar 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías lograrlo usando [`IIF`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) y [`ISNUMERIC`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Ejemplo**:

```
SELECT
    IIF(ISNUMERIC(Column_value) = 1, Column_value, NULL) AS Column_valueInt,
    IIF(ISNUMERIC(Column_value) = 1, NULL, Column_value) AS Column_Value_varchar
FROM test;
```

Resultado :

```
Column_valueInt | Column_Value_varchar
null            | perro
2               | null
null            | gato
1               | null
null            | pez
8               | null
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea8c9f83656aa808353162a21dc354d7)</kbd>

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado porque ISNUMERIC no valida que sean solo números y puede traer resultados inesperados con valores como '$', '+', ',', '-', '0d2345', '12e34', etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Esta es mi tabla de prueba:**
 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el resultado del query:**
 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ,
    Number INT 
)

DECLARE @Table2 AS TABLE(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Text VARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO @Table1 (Number)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Columna) = 1 THEN Columna ELSE NULL END AS Number
FROM 
    PRUEBA

INSERT INTO @Table2 (Text)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Columna) = 0 THEN Columna ELSE NULL END AS Text
FROM 
    PRUEBA

SELECT * INTO ##Temp1 FROM @Table1
SELECT * INTO ##Temp2 FROM @Table2

SELECT 
    Number AS Column_valueInt 
    , Text AS Column_Value_varchar
FROM ##Temp1
INNER JOIN
    ##Temp2 
ON 
    ##Temp1.Id = ##Temp2.Id


drop table ##Temp1
drop table ##Temp2
```

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado porque ISNUMERIC no valida que sean solo números y puede traer resultados inesperados con valores como '$', '+', ',', '-', '0d2345', '12e34', etc.